# SQL server permissions for PHP access

Tags: php, sql-server, permissions

I have a database that I try to work with. Unfortunately, I don't have much control over it. I was given a user and I perform all the queries using this user.
I created a C app that connects to this DB and performs some selects and inserts. Everything works well here.
But I also want to access this DB from the web interface. So I set a XAMPP on one of the PCs, installed sqlsrv extensions and tried to run this PHP code with the same user as in the C program.

```
 <?php
 
$serverName = "MYSERVER";
 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MYDB",
                         "UID"=>"userid",
                         "PWD"=>"userpwd");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
 
if( $conn === false )
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 
$wynik = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM MYDB.dbo.my_table");
if($wynik === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($wynik, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['user_name'].", ".$row['user_tag']."<br />";
}

?>
```

The result is:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 229
> [code] => 229 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'my_table',
> database 'MYDB', schema 'dbo'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the
> object 'my_table', database 'MYDB', schema 'dbo'. ) )

I used the same user for both and only the PHP one does not work. Could it be that the SQL server differentiates from where the client connects and I need to grant some PHP permissions to that user?

EDIT.
My connection string in C program is

> "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MYSERVER;DATABASE =
> MYDB;UID = userid;PWD = userpwd;"

while in PHP it is missing the driver entry. Setting it to "{SQL Server}" won't work. Maybe here is the problem?

EDIT2.
I tried prepared statements. I thought that maybe it had some protection against SQL injections but no... still no success.

EDIT3.
I asked the DB owner for permissions and it turned out that the user I used had no permissions granted at all... Anyway, now everything works fine. The biggest mystery is why my C app was allowed to operate without any permissions.

Comment: SQL server, unlike mySQL (for example), doesn't care which host you connected from

Comment: Are the C and PHP code running on two different computers? Possibly different DNS configuration (or HOSTS files) is causing the same host name to resolve to different IP addresses and so connect to two physically different SQL servers.

Comment: I edited my initial post.